# AWS: Correct way to attach a dead letter queue (DLQ) to an SNS publishing to Lambda using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am attempting to add a DLQ to the subscription between SNS and Lambda through CloudFormation to capture messages that could not be delivered.

I have managed to achieve this by:

1. Creating an SNS “Events” property in the Lambda CloudFormation
2. Creating an SNS Subscription with a DLQ for the RedrivePolicy and the same endpoint as the SNS.

I had to create both resources because the Lambda SNS Events property does not have a property for DLQs.

Is this the correct way to do this? It feels wrong that I need to configure both the SNSEvent ***and*** a subscription. But it the only way I can find that will let me attach a DLQ to the SNS subscription.

What if we just used the Subscription but didn't configure the SNSEvent in the Lambda. Could we get that to work if we implemented a generic handler in the Lambda?

The relevant CloudFormation configuration is below:

```yaml
 # ReceivedRequestSNS Role
   ReceivedRequestsSNS:
     Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
     Properties:
       TopicName: !Sub
         - ${StackName}-ReceivedRequests-${Stage}
         - StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
           Stage: !Ref Stage 

   # DLQ for SNS 
   ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQ:
     Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
     Properties:
       QueueName:  {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-ReceivedRequestsDLQ"}
       MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
       VisibilityTimeout: 5

   # Subscription
   ReceivedRequestsToLambdaSuscription:
     Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
     Properties:
       Protocol: lambda
       Endpoint: !Sub
         - ${LambdaArn}:live
         - { LambdaArn: !GetAtt TrainingNotificationsRequestsHandler.Arn }
       RedrivePolicy:
         deadLetterTargetArn : !GetAtt ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQ.Arn
       TopicArn: !Ref ReceivedRequestsSNS

   # DLQ Policy
   ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQPolicy:
     Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
     Properties:
       PolicyDocument:
         Version: "2012-10-17"
         Statement:
           -   
             Effect: Allow
             Principal: "*" 
             Action: sqs:SendMessage
             Resource: !GetAtt ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQ.Arn
       Queues:
         - !Ref ReceivedRequestsSNSDLQ

[...]

   TrainingNotificationsRequestsHandler:
     Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
     Properties:
       Handler: 'com.test.traininglambda.lambda.handlers.TrainingNotificationRequestsHandler::handleRequest'
       Runtime: java8
       DeadLetterQueue:
         Type: SQS 
         TargetArn: !GetAtt TrainingNotificationsRequestsHandlerDLQ.Arn
       Events:
         SNSEvent:
           Type: SNS 
           Properties:
             Topic: !Ref ReceivedRequestsSNS
```

Comment: The SNS event as part of the Lambda definition is just a wrapper and will be converted to a Subscription when SAM generates the final template. You don't need to do that if you are already defining the subscription separately.